# spread operator for object containing readonly

Tags: typescript, access-modifiers

My sample class:

```js
class Foo {
  private static counter = 1;

  readonly id: number;

  constructor() {
    this.id = Foo.counter++;
  }
}
```

I'm having 2 options:

- Make the constructor accepts another `Foo`, so that I can clone using `new Foo(foo)`
- Make `id` public, so that I can clone using `{ ...foo }`

Is there anyway to use spread clone AND keep `readonly` (or anything that prevents `id` from being modified from outside)?

Comment: <Pedantry>`...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what spread and rest syntax do.</Pedantry> :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 3 months ago I upvoted your comment just because `...` doesn't appear on [MDN operator page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators). It dawns on me now. It does not produces a value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use spread clone AND keep `readonly`...

No. The result of `{ ...foo }` is a plain object with read/write public data properties for the own, enumerable properties of `foo`. There's nothing you can add to your class to change that behavior.

Also note that because  `{ ...foo }` creates a plain object, it will no longer be an instance of `Foo`. If `Foo` defined any methods, for instance, the clone wouldn't have them. (In the code in the question, that kind of clone would be assignment-compatible with `Foo` because it *doesn't* define any methods. But if `Foo` had methods, it wouldn't be.)

If you want to use spread syntax *(it's not an operator)* to clone objects, don't use `class`, use `interface` since the clones won't inherit from the prototype the class will assign.

In this case, as you said, you can make `Foo`'s constructor optionally a copy-constructor:

```
class Foo {
    private static counter = 1;
  
    readonly id: number;
  
    constructor(other?: Foo) {
        if (other) {
            // Copying
            this.id = other.id; // Just to make TypeScript happy that `id` is
                                // definitely assigned on this path (it would be
                                // anyway, but TypeScript doesn't know that)
            Object.assign(this, other);
        } else {
            // Creating a new one
            this.id = Foo.counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

(Instead of the `this.id = other.id;` line, we *could* have marked `id` with the "definitely assigned" annotation [`readonly id!: number;`]. But since there are multiple paths through the constructor, I wouldn't do that, because it's too easy to forget about it when modifying the code. So I'd use the unnecessary assignment above.)